# Cannot remove Ubuntu & Install Windows 10 from single os Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04

My Fujitsu laptop has the single os Ubuntu 16.04. Now I want to remove Ubuntu & install Windows. I have followed all the possible ways I got. But nothing works.

I have tried with USB & also with DVD. There is no boot option without Ubuntu. Now this laptop has only one partition with 465GB(drive) approximate space & partition type is GPT.

Also tried os uninstaller. But it's not working.

What should I do now?

Comment: Installing an OS isn't dependent on any already installed OS therefore your question is Ill formed from the get go. Your question is actually how to install Windows 10. How to do that starts with a properly made installation USB then goes about knowing whether you have BIOS or UEFI and then choosing the adequate options including the partitioning type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took my laptop to a computer servicing center. They have checked it out and confirmed to me that there is a **problem in the motherboard**. For the motherboard, the bios aren't working properly. Thanks for helping me & also thanks to the person who has downvote the question without help.